# I have Web sockets working with nodejs locally, how do I put this onto test server?

Tags: node.js, apache, web, websocket, socket.io

I have something like this working successfully locally:
http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I want to test this out on my server hosted by Dreamhost.

I've done some research and people have said its not possible to do this wth a shared server and since Dreamhost dont allow SUDO user on the VPS's I cant do it using a VPS either.

So how do I go about doing this?

I know very little about servers so if someone could explain the steps on how I get my server to run "node index.js" that would be awesome.

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

TLDR:
I want to get web sockets to work on my server, it works locally when I use "node index.js" and access http://localhost:3000, but doesnt work when I use xampp and access it via http://mychatapp.dev (I assume because node isnt running). So how do I get node to run alongside my apache, locally and on my test server hosted by dreamhost.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you checkout their [doc](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Node.js) about using Node.js?

Comment: Oops, forgot to say. I've kinda got this working with a VPS hosted by Dreamhost. I've installed node onto the VPS and eveyrthing works fine. The only issue now is to figure out to how run node om my VPs all the time, but Im sure I can figure that out with a bit of googling.